# Trying to deploy rails app to Heroku, but I'm getting this error message midway through it building "! [remote rejected] (pre-receive hook declined)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am following along with Ruby on Rails Tutorial and have followed everything step-by-step. However when I put in

```
git push heroku main
```

It puts out this

```
  remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:                         Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.2.33
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.5
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.33
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching rake 13.0.6
remote:        Installing rake 13.0.6
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.15.0
remote:        Fetching zeitwerk 2.5.4
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.4
remote:        Installing zeitwerk 2.5.4
remote:        Installing minitest 5.15.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
remote:        Fetching erubi 1.10.0
remote:        Fetching racc 1.6.0
remote:        Installing erubi 1.10.0
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.6
remote:        Fetching rack 2.2.3
remote:        Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.6
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
remote:        Installing rack 2.2.3
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching marcel 1.0.2
remote:        Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Installing marcel 1.0.2
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Fetching msgpack 1.4.4
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Installing msgpack 1.4.4 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 2.2.33
remote:        Fetching ffi 1.15.5
remote:        Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Installing method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching pg 1.2.3
remote:        Installing pg 1.2.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching thor 1.2.1
remote:        Installing thor 1.2.1
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Fetching semantic_range 3.0.0
remote:        Installing semantic_range 3.0.0
remote:        Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching i18n 1.9.1
remote:        Installing i18n 1.9.1
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 2.0.4
remote:        Installing tzinfo 2.0.4
remote:        Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Installing rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Fetching rack-proxy 0.7.2
remote:        Installing rack-proxy 0.7.2
remote:        Fetching sprockets 4.0.2
remote:        Installing sprockets 4.0.2
remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.5
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.7.5 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching mail 2.7.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.13.1 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.13.1 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Fetching puma 5.3.1
remote:        Installing puma 5.3.1 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Fetching activesupport 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching bootsnap 1.7.2
remote:        Installing bootsnap 1.7.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.13.0
remote:        Installing loofah 2.13.0
remote:        Fetching sassc 2.4.0
remote:        Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Fetching globalid 1.0.0
remote:        Installing globalid 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching activemodel 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing activemodel 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.10.0
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.10.0
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
remote:        Fetching activejob 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing activejob 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching activerecord 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing activerecord 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching actionview 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing actionview 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching actionpack 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing actionpack 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching actioncable 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing actioncable 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching activestorage 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing activestorage 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching actionmailer 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing actionmailer 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching railties 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing railties 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.4.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.4.2
remote:        Fetching actionmailbox 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing actionmailbox 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching actiontext 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing actiontext 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching webpacker 5.4.0
remote:        Installing webpacker 5.4.0
remote:        Fetching rails 6.1.4.1
remote:        Installing rails 6.1.4.1
remote:        Fetching sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Installing sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Installing sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 56 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Bundle completed (174.62s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v16.13.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.17
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `group' for #<HelloApp::Application:0x0000559c74bae1e8>
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/config/environments/production.rb:5:in `block in <main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:234:in `instance_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:234:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/config/environments/production.rb:3:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:570:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:570:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_8540a8d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: e3c6e5a9acce3bb652ab8579c32c736a61f7381a
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version e3c6e5a9acce3bb652ab8579c32c736a61f7381a
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to secret-atoll-24278.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/secret-atoll-24278.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/secret-atoll-24278.git'
```

I'm new to Ruby and Heroku, so I'm having a hard time finding the difference between standard error messages and the ones that get to the root of the issue.

It's recognizing that it's a Ruby app, but it's getting tripped up somewhere along the way. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not a Ruby or Rails guy so can't help much on the error, but scroll up a bit. You want to be looking at `Running: rake assets:precompile` / `rake aborted!` / `NoMethodError: undefined method `group' for #<HelloApp::Application:0x0000559c74bae1e8>`.

Comment: What @Chris said. We would need to see the contents of the "config/environments/production.rb" file to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @engineersmnky Here is my github of production.rb https://github.com/JalenSowell2495/hello_app/blob/main/config/environments/production.rb

Comment: Lines 5-12 belong in the Gemfile not in the environment file

Comment: From the error message it is evident that you are using group method in you app and it is not defined. With the help of your text editor, you can search for text `group` throughout your application to find all its occurrences and then resolve manually.

`Running: rake assets:precompile / rake aborted! / NoMethodError: undefined method group' for #<HelloApp::Application:0x0000559c74bae1e8>`

Comment: Note that Git itself is merely a relay here: you use Git to send your code to GitHub, GItHub uses Git to send your code on to Heroku, Heroku compiles (or tries to compile) your code, gets an error, and uses the various Git transports to send the error message back to you doing your `git push`. But you might as well tag this with your browser's name, as tag it with Git, if you're reading SO with a browser...